# How to handle Asynchronous ordered Bulkwrite Exceptions while update records

Tags: mongodb

At what situation,generally update fails .I'm using bulkwrite operation for updating all the records.

Suppose if an exception occurs,while writing the data into a db,how to handle those exceptions ? can anyone please help me out regarding this ....

My code:

```
public void asyncWriteToMongo(String mappingName, List<WriteModel<Document>> documentList, String colName,
                String status) throws Exception {

            final CountDownLatch bulkLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            SingleResultCallback<BulkWriteResult> printBatchResult = new SingleResultCallback<BulkWriteResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(final BulkWriteResult result, final Throwable t) {

                    try {
                        updateStatus(name, result.getCount());
                        System.out.println(result +" "+ t);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        t.setStackTrace(e.getStackTrace());
                    }
                    if (t != null) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    bulkLatch.countDown();
                }
            };

            ConnectionManager cm = new ConnectionManager();
            com.mongodb.async.client.MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = cm.getAsyncMongoClient();
            com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoDatabase.getCollection(colName);
            try{
            collection.bulkWrite(documentList,printBatchResult);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }

            bulkLatch.await();
        }
```